# Specify return codes with chef package?

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I'm installing an exe using chef's package resource and the run is failing with a return code of 3010. A return code of 3010 means the install was successful, but a reboot is required.

I can get around this by putting `ignore_failure true` on the resource, but I think this would let legitimate errors go through.

Chef's resource `windows_package` has a `returns` property which allows you to specify an array of possible return values. However, `windows_package` is deprecated in favor of the more generic `package` resource, but `package` does not have a `returns` property.

Is there some other way that I'm not aware of that would allow me to specify return codes with the generic `package` resource?

Current code structure:

```
package 'Install Something' do
    source source_location
    package_name name_of_package
    options argument_list
    action :install
    provider Chef::Provider::Package::Windows
    ignore_failure true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not deprecated, use `windows_package`.

Comment: I ended up just doing this, so I'll mark it as the right answer.